# Enable max_old_space_size flag on ChromeOS in Kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

We are building a Chrome kiosk app that handles multiple big video files at the same time, and we are hitting the 1.4G memory limit for a Chrome process on a 64bit system.

On Chrome desktop, it's possible to set the `--max_old_space_size=4096` flag from a shell to increase the memory limit to 4G. Is there a way to achieve the same on ChromeOS in Kiosk mode?